# Android :Facebook sdk-4.4.1 Login without default Login button error on permissions?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[image: error image]

i login to Facebook without Facebook login button but i have find this attention message:

submit for login review some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by facebook

this is my code

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
     callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
  LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this,Arrays.asList("user_photos"));

            loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {


                    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                        RequestData();


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not error message, its for developers.

You need to submit your application to facebook for additional permissions like accessing user photos, friend list or publish something on user wall.

check out [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review), [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/review) and [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit) for more information.

If you will login with the user from where application is created you will not get this message, once application is approved from Facebook this message will not come.

> If your app asks for more than than public_profile, email and
>   user_friends it will require review by Facebook before your app can be
>   used by people other than the app's developers.

**Permissions That Do Not Require Review**

> **Public profile (default) permissions** : The default includes some basic attributes about the person, which are part of a person's public
>   profile on Facebook. The default permissions are included as part of
>   every permissions request, but require slightly different handling on
>   the web and native mobile platforms.
>
> **App friends** : This optional permission grants your app the ability to read a list of friends who also use your app.
>
> **Email permissions** : This gives you access to the person's primary email address.

Comment: i changed the setting of facebook account to public app to let any one test my app , what do you mean by f you will login with the user from where application is created you will not get this message, once application is approved from Facebook this message will not come. @RRR

Comment: If you want to access this permission, you need to submit your app to facebook and get approval. After getting approval this message will not come.

Comment: aha do you mean after user accept this permissions this message will not shown again to user

Comment: not user, once facebook will approve your application this message will not come.

Comment: facebook will approve or disapprove my app? based for what ? @RRR

Comment: check links i have given in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check for "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" on the top of "App Review" Screen of your application and select it to "Yes".

Answer (score 1):

This is your permission dialog from facebook it manse if you select **ok** than **facebook** will give you result as per requesting permission by you like **email**,**public_profile**, **user** friends etc.

Comment: i know facebook login process , but i ask about this message submit for login review some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by facebook

Comment: If you want to access otherpermission, you need to submit your app to facebook developer console and get approval. After getting approval this message will not come